# connecting a view with tableview in storyboard using button

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am newbee,So please help me with big heart, How can we connect a UIview controller button click to uitableviewcontroller(it containing navigation bar also) in Story board?i tried lots please help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click (or hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while you click) on the button, and then drag to the navigation controller and you should see a line between the two controllers show up (and the navigation controller will be highlighted at the point you can let go and establish the segue). You'll see a pop up and you can describe whether it's a modal segue (which it looks like would be in this case because the parent view doesn't have a navigation controller of its own, whereas the child does) or whatever.

Incidentally, are those two "buttons" actually buttons with images, or image views? If image views, you'll want to replace them with buttons and set the button to a custom button, and then supply the image. It will look the same, but you'll have button functionality. You can't do segue's from plain old image views, only buttons.